# Getting the array of selected values of multiple-values selectize

Tags: selectize.js

I have a selectize element, and my goal is to get the array of selected objects.
`$('#my_selectize_input').val()` yields `"3,4,67"`. In order to transform it to the necessary form, I use the following:

`JSON.stringify($('#my_selectize_input').val().split(','))`,

which looks quite awkward. Is there a more elegant way to get the array of selected values ?

Answer (score 7):

[Documentation](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) says "items" is the initial selected values. I'm not exactly sure if this is the answer, but it seems to be working on my tries.

```
 $('#my_selectize_input')[0].selectize.items
```